# Can specify neither the sort key nor the distribution key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

What is wrong with my syntax? I cannot make a table and specify the sort keys and distribution column. I am the owner of the RedShift database. If I remove the `SORTKEY` and `DISTKEY` definition the statement works.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dev.sch.tbl (
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    cid VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    cc VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
)
ENCODE AUTO
DISTKEY ( cid )
SORTKEYS ( date, cc )
;
```

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "DISTSTYLE" Position: 267 [ErrorId:
> 1-6477b934-7ee598ef14c5f3604df79394]

Comment: `SORTKEYS` should be `SORTKEY`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I amended that and the error persists.

Comment: It is unwise to use keywords for column names.

Comment: It is also unwise to let Redshift select column encodings; it does a very, very poor job.

Comment: I'm guessing cid is a UUID - you should be using a varbyte(16).  A varchar(32), with not null, is 36 bytes long.  A not null varbyte(16) is 16 bytes long.  ideally you have an int4 or int8 and perform a lookup to a table with the UUIDs in.

Answer (score 1):

I removed `ENCODE AUTO` and amended `SORTKEYS` to `SORTKEY`. It fixed the problem.